# How to update HTML Email Template on Marketing Cloud via Rest using Apex?

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud

I'm trying to update an HTML Email Template that I have created on SFMC, I make a HttpRequest using the following call on Apex:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/{Id}
```

The body of the Json is the following:

> request.setBody('{"views":{"html":{"content":"'+htmlBody+'"}},"assetType":{"name":"htmlemail","id":208}}');

in where the variable *htmlBody* contains a valid HTML page.
If I make the call using an external tool (like Postman or Advanced Rest Client of Google) it works fine and the HTML Email template was successfully updated, but if I make the call on Apex (using POST, PUT or PATCH) then the following error appears:

**System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]**

I also tried to escape the quotes that the HTML contains and also use the simple quote but the same error keep appearing.

I really appreciate any suggestions!

Regards!

Alvaro